# Get number from a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a string for example "lorem 110 ipusm" and I want to get the 110
I already tried this:

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]/", $string, $ret);
```

but this is returning this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 0
)
```

I want something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 110        
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To catch any floating point number use:

```
preg_match_all("/[+-]?\d+[\d\.Ee+]*/", $string, $matches);
```

for example:

```
<?
$string = 'ill -1.1E+10 ipsum +1,200.00 asdf 3.14159, asdf';
preg_match_all("/[+-]?\d+[\d\.Ee+]*/", $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

when run gives:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "-1.1E+10"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "+1"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "200.00"
    [3]=>
    string(7) "3.14159"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `+` (1 or more match) operator:

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]+/", $string, $ret);
```

Also, are you trying to support signs? decimal points? scientific notation? Regular expressions also support a shorthand for character classes; `[0-9]` is a digit, so you can simply use `\d`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to mach more than one digit:

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]+/", $string, $ret);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `/\d+/` - that should solve it.