# help with php regexp

Tags: php, html, regex, parsing

I have table like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/jurisKaste/FvgeQ/

And I need to get array of all those numbers from id column...
im using **php** code and I have so far this piece of code from here.
**i must use php only!**
[Get number from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734187/get-number-from-a-string)

how could i modify this regexp to get a bit readable array ?
 so the complete code look like this

```
    $data = str_replace(",", ".", $data); // $data is that html code from fiddle!
    preg_match_all("/[+-]?\d+[\d\.Ee+]*/", $data, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
```

edit:
what about this ?

```
    $data = str_replace(",", "", $data);
    preg_match_all("/[0-9]{5,6}/",$data,$matches);
    print var_dump($matches);
```

it works for me...

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: Don't parse HTML wil REGEX, it's evil. Consider this [Excellent Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) someone else wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = str_replace(",", "", $data);
preg_match_all("/[0-9]{5,6}/",$data,$matches);
print var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it looks for the first `td` after each `<tr` then gets the number in between the `<td>` and `</td>`

```
preg_match_all("/\<tr.+?td.+?\>([\d,]+?)\</s",$string,$matches);
print "<pre>"; var_dump($matches); print "</pre>";
```

Comment: it's data from google spreadsheet structured query, it gives this id with comma... so i cut it out and use this regexp pattern... and it works... in example i have 6 digit id, but it can be 5 digit too... that's why i wrote {5,6}
$data = str_replace(",", "", $data);
preg_match_all("/[0-9]{5,6}/",$data,$matches);
print "<pre>"; var_dump($matches); print "</pre>";

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement($data);
foreach($xml->tr as $tr){
    echo $tr->td[0];
}
```